# The method openFragmentTransaction() is undefined for the type new ActionBar.OnNavigationListener(){}

Tags: android, android-actionbar, spinner, android-arrayadapter

When I'm referring to [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown) link to make a dropdown list, I got an error in Eclipse:

```
The method openFragmentTransaction() is undefined for the type new ActionBar.OnNavigationListener(){}
```

This is the segment of example code given by the website (to date):

```
mOnNavigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {
  String[] strings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.action_list);

  @Override
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long itemId) {

    ListContentFragment newFragment = new ListContentFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = openFragmentTransaction(); //<--ERROR HERE

    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment, strings[position]);
    // Apply changes
    ft.commit();
    return true;
  }
};
```

The problem is, I don't know where is this method coming from? My main activity class is `SherlockFragmentActivity`, and I import from `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction`. Pressing "ctrl+shift+o" won't help. Can someone give a pointer to the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the answer. Just change

```
FragmentTransaction ft = openFragmentTransaction();
```

to

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```